# How to adjust an application (JFrame) with every kind of screens?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screen-size, jinternalframe

i have been working on a **Swing** application that has a **JFrame** as principal Frame and it contains a lot of **JInternalFrames** inside of it , and when i installed it in every computer in the company, it seems that some computers screen size is lower and more tight then the screen in wish i had developed my application, and that is not useful,  so i am asking if i can adjust my application (Frames) to every kind of screen size, i am using **Swing** API.

Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the options shown here suggest you always use a layout. Do not leave your screen without layout (setLayout(null)) because if  you don't use layout might impact on different operating systems.

Answer (score 5):

You can check the size of the screen like this:

```
 Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

Then you can decide how much of the screen you want to cover. Say half the size of the screen.

```
 int h = screen.height / 2;
 int w = screen.width / 2;
```

Then set your JFrame to this new height and width.

```
myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(w, h));
```

Of course you will have to experiment a bit to see what size works for all your screen sizes. Alternatively you can simply maximise the Frame on start up.

Comment: I tried this option, but the matter is only the principal frame that recognize the changes but the other components stay as they are :D,

Comment: similarly you will want to set the size of the internal frames relative to the size of the outer frame.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the local maximum resolution with

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            Rectangle desktopBounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

then you can adjust your application accordingly
note that this is in AWT but for me it still got the right result